# How to use literal type in Scala 2.13

Tags: scala, scala-2.13

I'm trying Literal Types from Scala 2.13 and I encounter the following error :

```
scala> def double[A <: Singleton] = valueOf[A]
                                           ^
       error: No singleton value available for A.
```

Could you explain why ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that's working like that, but rather with the related typeclass [`ValueOf`](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/ValueOf.html):

```scala
object Foo

def foo[A : ValueOf] = valueOf[A]

scala> foo[Foo.type]

res2: Foo.type = Foo$@1c105c3a
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm now able to do cool things : scala> def add[A<: Int : ValueOf, B <: Int : ValueOf] = valueOf[A] + valueOf[B] scala> add[1, 2] res79: Int = 3

Comment: So we can implement dependent types?

Comment: @PavelFilatov you might want to check out the singleton-ops library for more in this vein.

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely sure of what you're trying, but here an example from the [doc](https://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/42.type.html):

```scala
def foo[T](implicit v: ValueOf[T]): T = v.value
```

> A `scala.ValueOf[T]` type class and corresponding `scala.Predef.valueOf[T]` operator has been added yielding the unique value of types with a single inhabitant